# Excel vba: Convert String to Datetime add it to new Column

Tags: excel, vba

So I have cells containing strings of date, such as:

```
14/04/2019 10:13:18 AM
```

how can I convert it to DateTime using vba?

I've tried using `.NumberFormat` but some of the cells got converted and some didn't:

[image]

My code is

```
Sub ConvertToDateTime()

    With Range("Data[Modified On]")
        .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```

And how do I insert converted value to a new column?
I've created a new column with:

```
    Dim Table As ListObject
    Dim newColNum As Integer

    Set Table = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Data")
    Table.ListColumns.Add.Name = "New Header"
```

Can I do it without looping?

Comment: How about you first copy the range to a new column and then you convert that column's format to a DateTime format?

Comment: add sample data which can be copy please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Some of the cell do got converted but some don't

That's because the date format on your PC is different than the data (it is mm/dd/yyyy while the data is in "dd/mm/yyyy")

This can't be fixed without looping. (as far as I know)
To fix that, you might need to do something like this:

```
Sub ConvertToDateTime()
    Dim Cell As Range, h As Long, c As Long
    Range("Data[New Header]").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM"
    c = Range("Data[New Header]").Column
    For Each Cell In Range("Data[Modified On]")
        If Right(Cell.Value, 2) = "PM" Then h = 12 Else h = 0
        Cells(Cell.Row, c).Value = DateSerial(Mid(Cell.Value, 7, 4), Mid(Cell.Value, 4, 2), Left(Cell.Value, 2)) + _
            TimeSerial(Mid(Cell.Value, 12, 2) + h, Mid(Cell.Value, 15, 2), Mid(Cell.Value, 18, 2))
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks!, i ended up using looping you showed me and add 6 hours to my original string, `Cells(Cell.Row, c).Value = DateAdd("h", 6, Cell.Value)`, i was wondering if i can do this without looping like in pyhton.

Comment: Interesting! Are you sure it works even with the dates where the day number is higher than the month number?
Slicing the string and feeding the numbers to `DateSerial` & `TimeSerial` makes sure that Excel understands the date correctly. Are you sure `DateAdd` does that too? (It did not on when I tested)

No, I am not aware of anything that can do this without looping in Excel.

Comment: i think yes, i check the converted date manually (not all), so far it converted and add the time correctly. :D

Comment: Don't forget to choose an answer as "acceptable" when you find one.